# How to make unspecified text not appear

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a template in word where I need to input information to some attributes, in this example I am making pests and those pests can have several values separated by commas, I accomplished that, but I need to remove the unspecified value in Pest Latin, that is, when I do not specify any value for it it should not print a blank parenthesis.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/JJipT.png
Here is my code:

```
<xsl:if test="exists(//topic[@outputclass='pestsGroup']/p[@outputclass='PestLatin'])">
<w:t xml:space="preserve"> (</w:t>
<xsl:for-each select="following-sibling::p[@outputclass='PestLatin' and preceding-sibling::p[@outputclass='TargetPest'][1][@id=$id]]">
 <xsl:choose>
  <xsl:when test="position()=1">
    <w:t xml:space="preserve"><xsl:value-of select="."/></w:t>
  </xsl:when>
<xsl:otherwise>
<w:t xml:space="preserve">, <xsl:value-of select="."/></w:t>
                                            </xsl:otherwise>
                                            </xsl:choose>
                                            </xsl:for-each>
                                            <w:t xml:space="preserve">)</w:t>
                                        </xsl:if>
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve] showing input, an executable code (not a snippet taken out of context) and the expected output (as code within your question, not image in external link).

Comment: Search testing for an empty node using string-length()